# Facebook debugger scraper doesn't understand PHP include

Tags: php, facebook, web-scraping, tags, include

This is a weird one...

I have various php pages which includes `head.php` to display header tags, for example:

certificate.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <? 
        $SEO_image = "custom_image.png";
        include_once "head.php";
        ?>
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

head.php

```
...
<?
if(!isset($SEO_image))          $SEO_image = "default_image.png";
?>

...
<meta property="og:image" content="<?echo $SEO_image; ?>">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200px">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="129px">
....
```

I include the `head.php` in many pages and when I load the site in a browser everything works according to plan. If the parent page first instanciates `$SEO_image` before the `include_once "head.php"` the page source shows me the correct image `custom_image.png`. Otherwise shows me the `default_image.png`.

But if I run the same url which in the browser displays `custom_image.png` by facebook's debugger scraper it says the og:image tag is `default_image.png`. This happens with all tags that use variables in the same way (first declared in the parent page to used inside the included php script).

Facebook scraper: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

It's like if facebook's scraper is doing the impossible and somehow disassociating the variables in the parent pages from the `head.php` page.

What do you think can be happening here?

Thank you!

**NOTE:** I am aware that the `og:image` tag requires the entire url. I edited the code to exclude the site. As I mentioned, when viewing the page sources in a browser everything works properly.

Comment: Include is a PHP thing that runs on your server. Facebook can't change anything on your server. Without knowing what the URL is that you have a problem with it is almost impossible to give any help

Comment: Exactly, that's why I find this very weird. The execution should return the same information either to the browser or to the scraper... I will see if I can share the URL. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: Fixed it! The problem was the `og:url` tag which was pointing to the main site page (which has the default image) and somehow the scrapper was following that url and being redirected to that page instead of the current. Thank you @WizKid for the quick reply!

Comment: Yea that is how it works :) Which without knowing the URL or you showing us what tags values you actually put in we would never been able to help you with